# Adding CSS to individual table row when a dropdown item is selected?

Tags: php, html, css, forms, html-table

I wanted to know the best way to achieve this. I have a form which is embedded in a table showing a list of orders. I have a dropdown list with three items. 'pending' 'approved' and 'disapproved' when a user selects one of the options and clicks update the status is changed for that individual row. What I would like is that the whole table row changes colour depending on the item which has been selected.

I know that this can be achieved using jQuery which i have got to work but I need it so that a class will be applied depending on the option value. can I do this using php? and applying a class to the option value server side so that when a user refreshes the page the individual table cell will remain highlighted?

```
echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly=true name="order_no['.$i.']" value="' . $row['Orderno'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly=true name="order_date['.$i.']" value="' . $row['Orderdate'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly=true name="order_ordered_by['.$i.']" value="' . $row['Orderedby'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly=true name="order_supplier['.$i.']" value="' . $row['Supplier'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly=true name="order_total_price['.$i.']" value="' . $row['totalprice'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly=true name="order_requested_by['.$i.']" value="' . $row['requestedby'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<select name="order_status['.$i.']" id="id" onchange="showUser(this.value)" >';
    echo '<option value = "Pending"   name="order_status['.$i.']" class = "pending"' . ($row['status'] == 'Pending' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Pending</option>';
    echo '<option value = "Approved"  name="order_status['.$i.']" class = "approved"' . ($row['status'] == 'Approved' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Approved</option>';
    echo '<option value = "Disapproved" name="order_status['.$i.']" class ="disapproved"' . ($row['status'] == 'Disapproved' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Disapproved</option>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="order_selected['.$i.']"/></td>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: You can add the class to the `<tr>` using jQuery also, use the `.addClass` or `.toggleClass` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My table uses one <tr> and is populated using a database.

Comment: are you comfortable using jQuery in your project?

Comment: @Champ: "I know that this can be achieved using jQuery which i have got to work" obviously yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the status as class name.

```
<?php echo '<tr class="' . $status . '"><td>...</td></tr>'; ?>
```

Where `$status` is the value of your submitted select-box.

EDIT:

For the sake of readyability i updated your code:

```
<tr class="<?php echo $status; ?>">
    <td>
        <input type="text" readonly=true name="order_no[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['Orderno']; ?>"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" readonly=true name="order_date[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['Orderdate']; ?>"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" readonly=true name="order_ordered_by[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['Orderedby']; ?>"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" readonly=true name="order_supplier[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['Supplier']; ?>"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" readonly=true name="order_total_price[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['totalprice']; ?>"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" readonly=true name="order_requested_by[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="' . $row['requestedby'] . '"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="order_status[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="id" onchange="showUser(this.value)" >
            <option value = "Pending"   name="order_status[<?php echo $i; ?>]" class = "pending"'<?php echo $row['status'] == 'Pending' ? ' selected=selected' : ''; ?>>Pending</option>
            <option value = "Approved"  name="order_status[<?php echo $i; ?>]" class = "approved"'<?php echo $row['status'] == 'Approved' ? ' selected=selected' : ''; ?>>Approved</option>
            <option value = "Disapproved" name="order_status[<?php echo $i; ?>]" class ="disapproved"'<?php echo $row['status'] == 'Disapproved' ? ' selected=selected' : ''; ?>>Disapproved</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="order_selected[<?php echo $i; ?>]"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

You should think about using different classes for your select values and your table rows.

A possible CSS-Markup could be:

```
table tr.Pending
{
    background-color: #FF0000;
} 
...
```

EDIT 2:
I added a bit of code that could possibly be your way to render the page:

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["order_no"]); $i++) :?>    
    <tr class="<?php echo $_POST["order_status"][$i]; ?>">
        <td>
            <input type="text" readonly=true name="order_no[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['Orderno']; ?>"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" readonly=true name="order_date[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['Orderdate']; ?>"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" readonly=true name="order_ordered_by[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['Orderedby']; ?>"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" readonly=true name="order_supplier[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['Supplier']; ?>"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" readonly=true name="order_total_price[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['totalprice']; ?>"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" readonly=true name="order_requested_by[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="' . $row['requestedby'] . '"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="order_status[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="id" onchange="showUser(this.value)" >
                <option value = "Pending"   name="order_status[<?php echo $i; ?>]" class = "pending"'<?php echo $row['status'] == 'Pending' ? ' selected=selected' : ''; ?>>Pending</option>
                <option value = "Approved"  name="order_status[<?php echo $i; ?>]" class = "approved"'<?php echo $row['status'] == 'Approved' ? ' selected=selected' : ''; ?>>Approved</option>
                <option value = "Disapproved" name="order_status[<?php echo $i; ?>]" class ="disapproved"'<?php echo $row['status'] == 'Disapproved' ? ' selected=selected' : ''; ?>>Disapproved</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="order_selected[<?php echo $i; ?>]"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But be careful displaying data that you have received from a client. You should always check it first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The status would either be 'pending' 'approved' or 'disapproved' would that mean adding a CSS class for each option like .approved{background-color:green} and this would automatically style each row? sounds like a good way of achieving this.

Comment: like   echo '<tr class = '.$status.'>';

Comment: Yes that is right. You have to add the class definition in your CSS.

Comment: I've added a CSS class for each of the statuses. I could not get it to work using the above code. I can however add a static class to see the table rows change colour like <tr class="Approved">

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I am not getting a value for '$status'

Comment: I have looked in firebug and a blank class is being applied

Comment: I edited my answer again. $status was a variable i suggested, that should be filled with the post-data from your form. Anyway, i added some code that should show you how to do this with your POST.

Comment: Thanks very much Tobias, It is now working. Instead of using Order_status for the <tr> I used echo '<tr class="' . $row['status'] . '">'; and this dynamically assigns the CSS class based on the option value stored in the database. Now every row is properly colored depending on the selection made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's sessions to keep which class is applied, and putting a check also to read the session value, so each time page is refreshed, you'll get your values back.

Answer (score 0):

I think jquery is the best way more than using sessions.You can add `id`(this should be unique for this you can use unique id coming from database) and `class` for `<tr>` and  update `<tr>` class using jquery like this `$("#tr_id").addClass("class_name");`